# Cannot associate an entity obtained from a transaction to another entity in Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, entity-relationship, objectify

I have some issues with Entity relationships in Objectify. My application is an event application where events have tickets of different categories; each ticket is owned by a user. I have a parent/child hierarchy like so Event > TicketType > Ticket. So, Event is @Parent of TicketType which is @Parent of Ticket.

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    ...
    @Load
    private Set<Ref<TicketType>> ticketTypes = new HashSet<Ref<TicketType>>();
    ...
}

@Entity
public class TicketType {
    ...
    @Parent
    private Ref<Event> event;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Ticket {
    ...
    @Parent
    @Load
    private Ref<TicketType> ticketType;
    ...
}
```

I create the Event inside a transaction like so:

```
Event ev = ofy().transact(new Work<Event>() {

    @Override
    public Event run() {
    // several statements constructing the event
        ev.setXXXX(X);
    ofy().save().entity(ev).now();
        // Now construct the TicketType entity, then associate it to its parent, Event
    TicketType tt1 = new TicketType("normal", 100, 7);
    tt1.setEvent(ev);
        ofy().save().entity(tt1).now();
        return ev;
    }

});
```

Using the returned `ev`, I create the tickets like so:

```
// Generate a VIP ticket
Ticket ticket1 = ev.generateTicket("vip");
// I set the owner with an already saved User entity
ticket1.setOwner(cl);
ofy().save().entity(ticket1).now();
// The user also has a list of all his tickets
cl.addTicket(ticket1);
```

Inside Event.generateTicket(...), I do:

```
public synchronized Ticket generateTicket(String type) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    for (Ref<TicketType> reftt : ticketTypes) {
        TicketType tt = reftt.get();
        if (tt.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
            if (tt.getAvailable() > 0) {
                Ticket newTicket = new Ticket(RandomGenerator.nextNumber(TICKET_NUMBER_LENGTH), tt);
                newTicket.setExpirationDate(getEndDate());
                // here I set the parent TicketType entity for this new Ticket
                newTicket.setTicketType(tt);
                // the number of available tickets of this type is decreased
                tt.setAvailable(tt.getAvailable() - 1);
                return newTicket;
            } else return null;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such type");
}
```

My problem is that the parent/child relationship seems to be respected only on the `Event` entity that properly has a list of all Event/TicketTypes (through the `ticketTypes` field, which is a `Set<Ref<TicketType>>`. But, the `TicketType` entity does not have the list of tickets (the `tickets` field is null, so not saved), and in the other direction, the `TicketType` parent reference in `Ticket` is null, so is the `Event` parent reference in `TicketType`, despite the assignments I did in both cases above.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong here. I do however believe that Objectify will not automatically load one-to-many relationships. The proper way to get all your ticket types would be to first load the Event entity and then perform an ancestor query for the ticket type.

Some advice:
It looks like you are designing your entities like you would design tables in a relational database. Such concepts do not apply to datastore. As stated in the objectify introduction you should imagine the datastore as a hashmap of a hashmap. It might me feasible to use a multivalue attribute which contains enum values for the ticket type in your ticket entity. Less entities is always a good thing in datastore.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen in the documentation that the @Load annotation also works on collection of entities, which means that the ticket types should load with the Event entity. Am I understanding it wrong? Also, the reason why I created the TicketType as an entity is because the type of ticket has many attributes and might have behaviors associated with it (how many are available?, price, discount policy, etc.). Can you give me a specific code example?